# In Outlook 2007 using VSTO 3.0, how to detect if the default store has changed since Outlook was started?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I'm doing something similar to this, but wondering if there is an event somewhere that I'm missing

```
Store DefaultStore
    {
        get
        {
            var defaultStore = mOutlookApp_Model.Session.DefaultStore;

            if ( defaultStore.StoreID == mDefaultStore.StoreID )
            {
                // the default store we set at startup is the same as the default store now, so all good
                return mDefaultStore;
            }
            else
            {
                // the user changed the default store, so restart the addin_app
                DefaultStoreChangedRestartAddIn.Fire();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    readonly Store mDefaultStore;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope there isn't anything like this in the API, so hand crafting something is the only way.